# addr_recv addr_from in version Message

Tags: protocol, packets

I need some clarification about the meaning of the addr_from and addr_recv fields
in the Version Message.

addr_recv: The network address of the node receiving this message 
does this mean the public IP of the node I am sending to ?

addr_from:The network address of the node emitting this message 
does this mean my public(external) IP address or my local IP address ?

Thanks ..

Answer (score 3):

So assuming node A sends a version message to node B then the two fields have the following meaning and value:

- `addr_recv`: node A says "I believe you are reachable via this IP", hence its value is B's public IP address, the IP this message was originally sent to.
- `addr_from`: node A says "I believe my external IP is this", hence this is what A believes its external IP to be (but may be different if A is behind a NAT and has not learned its true external address yet).

Comment: What happens if the information in these fields is incorrect or missing?

Comment: Bitcoin Core actually ignores `addr_from` in received version messages. `addr_recv` is used to influence the heuristic that determines which of the receiving node's IP addresses is publicly reachable.