# What is the purpose of addr_from and addr_recv in version message?

Tags: protocol, network

I understand from [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/29876/31712) the semantics of `addr_from` and `addr_recv`. It is not clear to me though what is their purpose. Don't we assume that the transport layer protocol takes care of, well, transport?

What happens if I send a version message where the information `addr_from` or `addr_recv` is missing or incorrect? E.g., in [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/50502/31712) the example code includes the following:

```
addr_recv = struct.pack("Q", 0)
addr_recv += struct.pack(">16s", "127.0.0.1")
addr_recv += struct.pack(">H", 8333)
addr_from = struct.pack("Q", 0)
addr_from += struct.pack(">16s", "127.0.0.1")
addr_from += struct.pack(">H", 8333)
```

If that works, why include anything meaningful in those fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered in [this comment](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/29872/addr-recv-addr-from-in-version-message/29876#comment84453_29876):

> Bitcoin Core actually ignores `addr_from` in received version
>   messages. `addr_recv` is used to influence the heuristic that
>   determines which of the receiving node's IP addresses is publicly
>   reachable.